# new spreadsheet not visible in google drive using .NET API

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I created a google spreadsheet using Google API NET like below. I am receiving no exception and from code i was able to retrieve file id also. But when I look in google drive I am not seeing file. Is there some thing I should do to notify google drive. I did a refresh my drive too. But no use. Any idea?

I authenticated my service like below:

authenticate.cs

```
public class SerivceAccount
    {
        private const string ServiceAccountEmail = "182464555438-@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
        private static readonly X509Certificate2 Certificate = new X509Certificate2("ADExpress.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        readonly ServiceAccountCredential _credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(ServiceAccountEmail)
               {
                   Scopes = new[]
                   {
                       "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",
                       DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                       "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
                   }
               }.FromCertificate(Certificate));

        public bool Authenticate()
        {
            var isAuthenticated = false;
            try
            {
                if (!_credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None).Result)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Access token request failed.");
                isAuthenticated = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception in Authenticating " + e.ToString());
            }

            return isAuthenticated;
        }

        public ServiceAccountCredential Credential
        {
            get { return _credential; }
        }

    }
```

main.cs

```
var account = new SerivceAccount();
if (account.Authenticate())
            {
    FilesResource.InsertRequest request = service.Files.Insert(new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File()
                        {
                            Title = "Test",
                            Description = "Test",
                            MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
                        });
                        var file = request.Execute();
 Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);
}
```

Comment: how is service authenticated?

Comment: @DalmTo, I updated my question with authentication request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are authenticating using a service account.

> I did a refresh my drive too

Checking your own Google Drive web version will not show you the files that where created by a service account. Service account is its own user. Your file is probably being created on the service accounts Google Drive account you can test that by doing [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list)

**example:**

```
/// <summary>
  /// Retrieve a list of File resources.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="service">Drive API service instance.</param>
  /// <returns>List of File resources.</returns>
  public static List<File> retrieveAllFiles(DriveService service) {
    List<File> result = new List<File>();
    FilesResource.ListRequest request = service.Files.List();

    do {
      try {
        FileList files = request.Execute();

        result.AddRange(files.Items);
        request.PageToken = files.NextPageToken;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
        request.PageToken = null;
      }
    } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken));
    return result;
  }
```

In order for another user to see the file you must grant them permission to see the file created by the service account.

Answer (score 0):

Actually This helps to resolve my issue. I need to provide permissions to the file to be visible in UI interface. Hope this helps.

```
Permission newPermission = new Permission();
newPermission.Value = "yourdriveaccount@domain.com";
newPermission.Type = "user";
newPermission.Role = "reader";
service.Permissions.Insert(newPermission, file.Id).Execute();
```